# Desabilitar datas após a data atual DataPicker

Tags: jquery, datapicker

Estou querendo desabilitar as datas após a data atual no dataPicker. Sei como desabilitar as datas anteriores com a linha:

```
startDate: "date"
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém como esse dataPicker seria para o campo Data de Nascimento, não acho necessário as datas após a data atual estarem habilitadas, somente as datas anteriores. Entendo que poderia e farei a validação pela programação, mas se conseguisse desabilitar iria ajudar bastante.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui resolver. Usei a lógica. Se startDate: "date" desabilita as datas anteriores, então se eu colocasse:

```
endDate: "date",
```

Ele desabilitaria as datas posteriores e foi isso que ocorreu:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código:

```
<div class="md-input-wrapper" id="sandbox-container">
    <input type="text" class="md-form-control">
    <label for="email">Data de Nascimento</label>
</div>
    <script>
        $('#sandbox-container input').datepicker({
            language: "pt-BR",
            format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
            endDate: "date",
            todayHighlight: true
        });
    </script>
```